# How to match the question id in the nested table to the main table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, antd

```
const questionsData = [
{
  
      key: '16',
      qn_total_mark: '5',
      part_desc: 'cheese',
},
{
  
      key: '16',
      qn_total_mark: '5',
      part_desc: 'Potato',
},
{
  
      key: '17',
      qn_total_mark: '5',
      part_desc: 'Now',
}
{
  
      key: '17',
      qn_total_mark: '5',
      part_desc: 'Now',
}
    ]

const columns = [
        {
            title: 'Question No',
            dataIndex: 'key',
            key: 'question_no',
        },
        {
            title: 'Total Marks',
            dataIndex: 'qn_total_mark',
            key: 'qn_total_mark',
        },
    ]
const expandedRowRender = () => {
        const columns = [
            {
                title: 'Part Description',
                dataIndex: 'part_desc',
                key: 'key',
            },
        ]
        return (
            <Table
                columns={columns}
                dataSource={questionsData}
            />
        )
    }

return (
        <>
            <Table
                columns={columns}
                dataSource={questionsData}
                expandable={{ expandedRowRender }}
            />
        </>
    )
```

what i am trying to do is create a nested table to store the part_desc respective to the question no (a.k.a key) , however my nested table right now gives back all the part desc regardless of the question number,is there a way to match the question number and the part description togehter

Comment: are you using any component library ?

Comment: im currently using ant design table hence the antd tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expandedRowRender` takes additional arguments , out of which one argument is `record` which holds the data of the row which you are expanding.

```
const expandedRowRender = (record) => {
            const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'Part Description',
                    dataIndex: 'part_desc',
                    key: 'key',
                },
            ]

// filter the data based that matches the record.key
const filteredData = questionsData.filter(data => data.key === record.key);
    
return (
         <Table
            columns={columns}
            dataSource={filteredData}
         />
       )
}
```